# Use Event Notifications to track new signers for draft envelope

Tags: c#, docusignapi

My application needs to use both API and Web Portal to prepare DocuSign envelope:

1. Use API to upload document and initial list of signers
2. Open web portal to review list of signers and place tabs

My question is: **Is there any way to get notified when user add new recipient through web portal?**

Initially I was thinking to use [customFields for signers](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7CSend%2520an%2520Envelope%2520or%2520Create%2520a%2520Draft%2520Envelope%7CRecipient%2520Parameters%7C_____7) but it's not implemented in [DocuSign .NET Client](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client).

I also know there is a [eventNotification](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope.htm?Highlight=eventNotification) functionality in DocuSign but it seems that it triggers by envelope and recipient status change and ot covers my case.

Comment: I can not think of a workflow that would perform the behavior that you're looking for. However you could get step 2 to be embedded sending, and also trigger an envelope status when it's completed.

Comment: @Anubis I'm not sure what your actual use case is but have you thought about using one of the various recipient types such `agents`, `editors`, or `intermediaries` ?  Those recipients can edit subsequent recipient information and add recipients etc